# Printing a HTML page without page information

Tags: html, css

I am trying to print a webpage without page information.

With page information I mean: The  of the page, URL of the page and the print pages and the date of the printing.

I am using the following code for it:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
 @page 
 {
  size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
  margin-bottom: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
  margin-top: 1mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
 }
</style>
```

This code seems to be working on Google Chrome. But in Mozilla Firefox I still get the 'page information'.

So my question is, why is this code not working on other browsers (Mozilla Firefox) and how can I fix this so it will work on Mozilla Firefox and other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are more browser settings than website settings. Yet you can use `@page` rule. Right now it will work only with Google Chrome (just like you wrote).

```
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 4mm; }
}
```

About the [@page on W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/page.html).

For Mozilla Firefox you can try:

```
<html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint>
```

See [this](https://bug743252.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=714383).

Answer (score 0):

Although in many cases this is determined by browser side settings, you might be able to have it behave more as you wish by using:

```
@media print {
    #Header, #Footer { display: none !important; }
}
```

[Source](https://springmerchant.com/bigcommerce/hide-header-footer-when-printing-bigcommerce/)